# How to get consolidated errors in column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement which needs to find out **consolidated error report** of all columns containing error report. Is there any function or any ways to do this in SQL Server?

I tried this using a `CASE` statement but it only gives error report for one column.

[image]

I need the result like this after applying filter or procedure

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag the question with the Oracle 10g tag, if you use MS SQL Server?

Comment: Why tag 2 different versions of SQL Server, both of which are out of support and one of which is completely unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE`:

```
select 
  row,
  case when length(name) > 10 
       then 'Name max=10 Present=' + length(name) + '; ' 
       else '' end +
  case when length(place) > 10 
       then 'Place max=10 Present=' + length(place) + '; ' 
       else '' end +
  case when length(address) > 10 
       then 'Address max=10 Present=' + length(address) + '; ' 
       else '' end as error
from t
```

Comment: I was trying with one case Statement so it was giving error report for one column. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!!